# take print in list view on calender

Tags: css, printing

I need to list view when am taking the print
it is possible to archive media print css?
now i am getting like the below img
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6mPO.png)

but i want the print form like below img

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZJAb.jpg)

Comment: Yes it is. Can you add some of your code here? Or a fiddle link

Comment: how can i add the css

Comment: using `@media print {}`, more info here : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of https://fullcalendar.io/

Since you have not posted any code, I have taken a random calendar with a print button. So on click of print I'm changing the calendar view and calling `window.print()` method.

Change view : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/changeView/

https://jsfiddle.net/7xcqaLpq/7/

Answer (score 0):

here is your html code

```
<div class="" id="component1">
      <full-calendar></full-calendar>
    </div>
```

add print button and pass the id into method

```
<button (click)="printComponent('component1')">Print</button>
```

--

```
printComponent(cmpName) {
        var docHead = document.head.outerHTML;
        var printContents = document.getElementById('component1').outerHTML;
        var winAttr = "location=yes, statusbar=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no,dependent=no, width=865, height=600, resizable=yes, screenX=200, screenY=200, personalbar=no, scrollbars=yes";
    
        var newWin = window.open("", "_blank", winAttr);
        var writeDoc = newWin.document;
        writeDoc.open();
        writeDoc.write('<!doctype html><html> <style>.fc-header-toolbar{display :none !important;} .fc-scroller.fc-scroller-liquid{overflow:visible !important;} .fc-view-harness.fc-view-harness-active{height:auto !important;}</style>' + docHead + '<body onLoad="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
        writeDoc.close();
        newWin.focus();
      }
```

using this you can take a print of calendar